# Building OpenSSL on Win32, with zlib

Tags: windows, visual-studio, openssl, zlib

I'm trying to build Open SSL on Windows using VS 2013, with ZLIB support.

I follow the instructions this way: 
perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix="D:\work_local\openssl\openssl-1.0.1h\redist" no-asm zlib no-shared

ms\do_ms

nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

Now I get linker error, saying zlib1.lib is not found.

What is surprising, is that it didn't complain about not finding zlib.h.

So how do I pass ZLIB include and LIB path while building OpenSSL on Windows?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add --with-zlib-include=[path to zlib headers] --with-zlib-lib=[path to zlib static library]